# aws api gateway client not executing .then, it is just exiting apigClient function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-api-gateway

This is my first app using AWS API gateway and I was able to pull data when the function was called within componentDidMount now I'm calling the module like this from my component class

```
componentDidMount (){
  // debugger
  this.setState({apiData: apiCall(this.state.testSearch) })
this.updateAPIdata()

}
```

and apiCall is a function in methods.js

```
const apiCall = function(searchInput) {
  const searchTerm = searchInput
  var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;

  const config =  {
                apiKey: 'xxxxxx',
                invokeUrl:'https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
                }

  var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(config);
  var params = {
        //This is where any header, path, or querystring request params go. The key is the parameter named as defined in the API
        //  userId: '1234',
        search_keyword: 'Ambassador'
      };
      // Template syntax follows url-template https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-template
  var pathTemplate = '/beta/testDB'
  var method = 'GET';
  var additionalParams = {
      //If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that need to be sent with the request you can add them here
      headers: {

            },
      queryParams: {
        search_keyword: 'Ambassador'
              }
    }
debugger
    apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
             .then(function(result)
                {
                    //This is where you would put a success callback
                    return JSON.parse(result.data)

                }).catch( function(result){
                    //This is where you would put an error callback
                })
}
```

when I debug the code all the right variables are passed to apigClient.invokeApi but it never goes to the then function it just jumps to the last closing } on the apiCall function. This is unexpected, as before it would debug the next like then(function(result).

Am I calling the function wrong or some other newbie mistake? This code worked when it was in the same .js file as componentDidMount.

Comment: This function is pulled from
https://github.com/kndt84/aws-api-gateway-client

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Has [CORS been enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)? Lastly, inside your AWS console, are you able to test the API Gateway method and do you get a successful response?

Comment: This code was pulling data from the gateway before I moved it into its own method.js file. So I know that the configuration on AWS works. I am not getting any errors. the code is running the apigClient.invokeApi function but when it returns from the function it does not execute the .then it shows the next debugging line of the final } for the apiCall function. It's really confusing as I am expecting the debugger to run the line ".then(function(result)" but it skips right past it.

Comment: If it skips right past it, does it go into the `catch()` statement? Have you tried logging something to double-check?

Comment: Here is exactly what the debugger is doing.https://youtu.be/GdJFx2BMd3o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning your results only after resolving the response from your API, which happens asynchronously.

There are two ways to fix this

- Using a callback

`

```
componentDidMount() {
  apiCall(this.state.testSearch, (data, error) => {
    if (error) {
      //handle
      console.log(error)
      return
    }
    this.setState({apiData: data})
    this.updateAPIdata()
  }
}

const apiCall = function(searchInput, callback) {
  //...Your code
  apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
    .then((result) => {
      callback(JSON.parse(result.data))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      callback(null, error)
    })
}
```

- Using async await (my pref)

`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const data = await apiCall(this.state.testSearch)
    this.setState({apiData: data})
    this.updateAPIdata()
  } catch(e) {
    //Handle error
  }
 }

 async function apiCall(searchInput) {
   //...Your code
   const result = await apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
   return JSON.parse(result)
 }
```

Comment: I found that the apiCall was executing properly but it was not re-rendering the data that was returned.

Comment: Yes, because of reasons mentioned in my answer.